# How to execute a LINQ query while constructing an XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to create a table that list the count of each file type. I've created a query to get that data. When I create the XDocument, how do I execute the query and create rows in the table with data from query?

```
    var query = listFiles.GroupBy(f => Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower())
        .Select(g => new
        {
            Extension = g.Key,
            Count = g.Count(),
        });

    var doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("html", 
            new XElement("body",
                new XElement("table", new XAttribute("border", 2),

                        foreach (var f in query)
                        {
                            new XElement("tr",
                                new XElement("td", f.Extension),
                                new XElement("td", f.Count));
                        }))));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
var doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("html", 
            new XElement("body",
                new XElement("table", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("border", 2),
                    query.Select(f =>
                            new XElement("tr",
                                new XElement("td", f.Extension),
                                new XElement("td", f.Count)))
                        }))));
```